# Yii Not able to route requests to different paths

Tags: php, yii, url-mapping, yii-routing

I have a problem while routing my requests in Yii. Following is the urlManager rules:

```
'rules'=>array(

                array('api/index', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*', 'verb'=>'GET'),
                array('api/shortlist', 'pattern'=>'api/<action>/<model:\w+>/*', 'verb'=>'GET'),
                array('api/compare', 'pattern'=>'api/<action>/<model:\w+>/*', 'verb'=>'GET'),

                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

My requests get routed to `api/shortlist` even if I hit the `api/compare` link.

What am I doind wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the patterns for your `shortlist` and `compare` rules are the same.

Therefore, the rule that is placed first will match for both, and the second one will never run.

Your `api/compare` rule will never match/hit because the rule above it is the same and will match first.

You should have done something like this to prevent conflict:

```
'api/shortlist' => 'api/shortlist/<action>/<model:\w+>/*',
'api/compare' => 'api/compare/<action>/<model:\w+>/*',
```